# Using Cordova identify iOS device type iphone or ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, sencha-touch

I have submitted one iOS application developed using Cordova/Sencha Touch but it being rejected.

I have one functionality which will behave different for iphone and ipad. I am using this code to identify device type :

```
Ext.os.deviceType.toLowerCase() == "phone"
```

But this always returns **"phone"** even if I run this app on **ipad simulator**.

So, how to fix this issue so I can submit this app successfully to app store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Cordova I use the following functions to detect platform:

```
function isAndroid() {
    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") > 0;
}
function isiOS() {
    return (isiPhone() || isiPad());
}
function isiPhone() {
    return (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPod") > 0) || $(window).width() <= 320;
}
function isiPad() {
    return navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") > 0 || ($(window).width() <= 1000 && $(window).width() > 320);
}
```

The `$(window).width()` is to help testing on desktop.

Comment: I have check this on iphone and ipad simulator with this "navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") > 0" and in both it return "true". And I think by going with width conditions is not a good choice.

Comment: Width conditions are to help emulating it on desktop (for example to test on a Chrome browser). You can remove it for production code. On my devices this code works. I haven't checked it on emulator. Can you show us your navigator.userAgent on the emulator?